# Error with docpad-plugin-gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, docpad

I'm trying to use the gulp docpad plugin and I get the following error when I execute `docpad run`:

```
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
at exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:339:9)
at Task.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\docpad-project\node_modules\docpad-plugin-gulp\node_modules\safeps\es5\lib\safeps.js:595:43)
at ambi (C:\Projects\docpad-project\node_modules\ambi\es5\lib\ambi.js:101:14)
at Domain.fireMethod (C:\Projects\docpad-project\node_modules\taskgroup\out\lib\taskgroup.js:397:23)
at Domain.run (domain.js:191:14)
at Task.fire (C:\Projects\docpad-project\node_modules\taskgroup\out\lib\taskgroup.js:435:27)
at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Projects\docpad-project\node_modules\taskgroup\out\lib\taskgroup.js:452:26)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:374:17)'
```

Everything works after uninstalling the plugin.

Comment: Just realized this seems to be documented as an issue [here](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-livereload/issues/20). But does anyone have workarounds they've tried?

Comment: Do you use this gulp plugin anywhere? If so, show us the code

Answer (score 1):

<s>Not sure what caused the error, but running Docpad in an **elevated command prompt** solved the problem for me. I'm working on **Windows** 10. (I bet this issue is Windows related.)</s>

To open a cmd with admin privileges, hit menu start and type `cmd`. Then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> or hit the right mouse button and select 'run as administrator'. The solution works in a Git Bash terminal with extra privileges, as well.

**Edit:** Today it broke again :/ (to the point that I question whether it did work yesterday...) The quest for an answer has started again...

**Edit 2:** The error is caused by `docpad-plugin-gulp` (or its dependencies) for sure; running the Gulp tasks directly works fine.
However, I found a [setting](https://github.com/terminalpixel/docpad-plugin-gulp#configure) in `docpad-plugin-gulp` called `background`. Setting this to `true` will run Gulp in the background. More important is that it removes the experienced errors altogether. This leads me to suspect the issue is caused by rule 64-67 of the plugin (`out/gulp.plugin.js`) or the functions it calls there:

```
this.safeps.spawn(command, {
    cwd: rootPath,
        output: true
    }, next);
```

I hope people more knowledgeable of this topic can confirm my suspicions and/or fix the plugin. For now, updating your `docpad.coffee` like below should bypass the errors.

```
docpadConfig = {
    # Other docpad settings

    plugins:
        gulp:
            background: true

}
module.exports = docpadConfig
```